# Providing same dates in JPA criteria API not returning result

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

I am providing same dates in start date and end date, but criteria API is not returning a record even though the record exists

```
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(employeeEntity_.lastUpdate), filter.getMinDate()));
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get(employeeEntity_.lastUpdate), filter.getMaxDate()));
employeeQuery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
employeeQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(root.get(employeeEntity_.id)));
TypedQuery<Long> query = entityManager.createQuery(employeeQuery);
List<Long> resultList = query.getResultList();
```

when the above code runs it returns 0 record even though the record exists
e.g

```
1- if I give 2017-04-14 - 2017-04-14 it displays 0 record
2- if I give 2017-04-14 - 2017-04-17 it displays 1 record
3- If I give 2017-04-13 - 2017-04-14 it displays 0 record
```

I want if same dates are provided as could be seen in example 1 it should display 1 and also example 3 should also return 1 record.

Native Query which I have run on mysql console

```
select * from Employee where LAST_UPDATE >= '2017-04-14 05:00:00' and LAST_UPDATE <= '2017-04-14 05:00:00'
```

Comment: Can you add the rest of the code that is referenced in this piece of code? Also, are you trying to create a dynamic query that varies more than changing parameters? If not then consider using entityManager.createQuery() or entityManager.createNamedQuery() or if you are using Spring @Query() or @NamedQuery() annotations. They are more readable and easier to debug.

Comment: @andrei-macarie I am using entityManager.createQuery

Comment: yes I wanted to say - `Query createQuery(String qlString)`. Sorry for not adding String in the parameters list.

Comment: @andrei-macarie I have made a native query on DB and the results are same

Comment: there is createQuery(String), createNamedQuery(String) and createNativeQuery(String) - so there is the JPQL syntax vs native SQL syntax.

Comment: does the native query return what you want? If so then just do: `entityManager.createQuery("select e from Employee e where lastUpdate >= :lastUpdateStart and lastUpdate <= :lastUpdateEnd)` then pass the parameters `lastUpdateStart` and `lastUpdateEnd`. This should be in JPQL language not native SQL.

Comment: @andrei-macarie I have finally resolved it by give the time range on both maxDate and minDate :)